# variable being reset in a 'for loop'

Tags: javascript, database, for-loop, calendar, phonegap

I am pushing info from a database to a calendar, where each date has an id equal to an id in the database. The code iterates through the database searching for matching pairs. If a match is found, the name of the image is to be placed into image tags in the calendar. However, the default image is the only one showing, and the variable calImg is seemingly being reset to default. `var idCalendar = [];
var arrayCalendar = -1;
var calImg;` are global variables

```js
while (counter <= numOfDays) {
  var dateID = counter + monthIDName;
  idCalendar[counter - 1] = dateID;
  //alert(idCalendar[counter-1]);
  // When to start new line.
  if (weekdays2 > 6) {
    weekdays2 = 0;
    htmlContent += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (mydb) {
    //Get all the entry from the database with a select statement
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
      t.executeSql("SELECT rating FROM entry WHERE calendar=?", [idCalendar[arrayCalendar + 1]], function(t, results) {
        var i;
        //Iterate through the results
        if (results.rows.length != 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = results.rows.item(i);
            calImg = row.rating;
            alert(idCalendar[arrayCalendar] + calImg);
          }
        } else {
          alert(idCalendar[arrayCalendar]);
          calImg = 'default';
        }
      });
      arrayCalendar++;
    });
  } else {
    myApp.alert("query error");
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // if counter is current day.
  // highlight current day using the CSS defined in header.
  if (counter == day && month == curMonth && year == curYear) {
    htmlContent += "<td class='dayNow' id='" + counter + monthIDName + "'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' " + "onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"; this.style.color=\"#FF0000\"'>" + counter + "<img src= 'img/" + calImg + ".png' align='left' height= '15' width= '15'>" + "<br>" + "</td>";
  } else {
    htmlContent += "<td class='monthNow' id='" + counter + monthIDName + "' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#FF0000\"'" + " onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'>" + counter + "<img src= 'img/" + calImg + ".png' align='left' height= '15' width= '15'>" + "<br>" + "</td>";
  }
  weekdays2++;
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: Because you have zero rows in the resultset?

Comment: calImg gets overwritten lots, what are the results of the alert in the middle of your for loop?

Comment: alert result is a popup showing the id of any date that has a value entered into it, along with the name of calImg. e.g. I have a value in yesterday, and today, so I get two popups. One saying 16August2017sad, and the second saying 17August2017vSad. sad and vSad are the entries in 'rating' in the database

Comment: You are making ajax call to fetch image info, but have no callback on success, instead the system carries on and assigns default value to the image variable.